# Schema design for objects that must be created in order yet are closely related if not the same

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design, schema

A Team Captain must be created by an Admin. once created, a Team Captain can then create the rest of his/her Team by adding members. Does it make more sense to have a separate Team Captain table or just to assign a Team Member Role (captain or member) inside of the Team table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the captain has substantially different business logic to a team member, they should be the same model.

You could handle the difference using roles as you mentioned, or (assuming you have a `Team` model which they all belong to), have the captain related to the team through a separate association.

Something like the following:

```
class Team
  has_one :captain, class_name: 'TeamMember'
  has_many :team_members
end
```

Answer (score 1):

My first question here is: When you think about a Team Captain, will you need to store any information about that person that will be *insensible* in context of the team members? And: will captains need to have substantial amounts of behavior or logic associated with their object model, that isn't relevant to other team members? If either of these answer yes, then you might end up with a cleaner schema in the long run if you split off captains now.

For example, if you'll end up needing several columns to store the team captain's favorite foods and music, but you don't care about this info for the rest of the team members, then it's starting to look like "team captain" and "team member" are actually different animals, if closely related.

Also, will you need to track which Team Captain is captain for which teams? If so, that could make your schema a bit simpler. If *the only thing that makes a team captain special* is the fact that they're captaining a team, then you could consider a many-to-many schema, roughly like this:

- team_members (id, name, favorite color, whatever)
- captains_to_teams (member_id, team_id)
- members_to_teams (member_id, team_id)
- teams

Or maybe even simpler, if you trust that each person will only be associated with a single team, and if you don't need to track changes in captainship or membership over time:

- team_members (id, name, favorite color, team_id, is_captain)
- teams (id, name)

In either of the above two scenarios, I'm assuming that you don't need to store "much" additional info about the team captains, so captains are allowed to live alongside (and as) team members. But if you find that you need to track substantially more info about captains, info that is irrelevant to team members, then it might be prettier and more kosher to split captains off into a separate table.